# Android onHandleIntent IntentService waits for UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, intentservice

I noticed that if i call startService from UI thread, onHandleIntent is not called until after UI thread is released. i.e onHandleIntent is blocked by UI Thread. I tried calling startService in a AsyncTask, still onHandleIntent call is blocked until UI thread is released. 
Is this is a **behavior (or bug ??) in Android** ? or I am doing anything wrong? I am testing it in Android 6.0.

Here is my Intent Service

```
public class TestIntentService extends IntentService {

     private static final String TAG = TestIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

     public TestIntentService() {
          super(TAG);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent Called");

          try {
               for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
                   Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent After " + i + " seconds");
               }

               synchronized (MainActivity.handle) {
                    MainActivity.handle.notify();
               }

          } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
          }
     }
}
```

Here is the method in my Activity that will be called on click of a button where I am calling start Service

```
protected void onStartServiceButtonClicked(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "startServiceClicked");

    Intent intent = new Intent(context,  TestIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "After calling startService");


    synchronized (handle) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Before waiting");
            handle.wait(4000);
            Log.d(TAG, "After handler Wait");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and `handle` is just an activity class member variable `public static Object handle = new Object();`

Here is the adb log

```
08-24 10:06:27.777 13564-13564/com.kl.testintentservice D/MainActivity: startServiceClicked
08-24 10:06:27.778 13564-13564/com.kl.testintentservice D/MainActivity: After calling startService
08-24 10:06:27.778 13564-13564/com.kl.testintentservice D/MainActivity: Before waiting
08-24 10:06:31.778 13564-13564/com.kl.testintentservice D/MainActivity: After handler Wait
08-24 10:06:31.782 13564-13564/com.kl.testintentservice I/Choreographer: Skipped 252 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-24 10:06:31.783 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent Called
08-24 10:06:32.784 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent After 1 seconds
08-24 10:06:33.784 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent After 2 seconds
08-24 10:06:34.785 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent After 3 seconds
08-24 10:06:35.786 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent After 4 seconds
08-24 10:06:36.786 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent After 5 seconds
08-24 10:06:37.786 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent After 6 seconds
08-24 10:06:38.786 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent After 7 seconds
08-24 10:06:39.787 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent After 8 seconds
08-24 10:06:40.787 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent After 9 seconds
08-24 10:06:41.787 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: onHandleIntent After 10 seconds
08-24 10:06:41.787 13564-16520/com.kl.testintentservice D/TestIntentService: handle notified
```

Comment: its not a bug, its a feature, you are not doing anything wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is perfectly normal. It is not unique to `IntentService`. Any `startActivity()`, `startService()`, `bindService()`, or `sendBroadcast()` call will not even begin doing its work until you return from whatever main application thread callback you are on.

Since tying up the main application thread in a callback for more than 1ms is poor practice, this behavior should not impact very many developers.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely do not want to block the UI thread. My intention is to synchronize data from async Intent service. The service i have gets data through BLE and it is asynchronous and usually i get the data back in 500ms. So i wanted to see if i can wait at a max for a minute in the UI thread so the UI component need not worry about callback and simply get the data in the synchronous call. The UI component will call a facade and facade will wait for 1 second and if it can't get the data it will throw an exception. UI component just needs to handle the exception

Comment: @KannanLoganathan: "So i wanted to see if i can wait at a max for a minute in the UI thread so the UI component need not worry about callback and simply get the data in the synchronous call" -- no. First, you have the problem that you cited in your question. Second, your UI would be completely frozen during this time. Third, if you tie up the main application thread for several seconds, Android terminates your app, as it assumes that your app is horribly broken.